# Making SharePoint list columns searchable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-list, enterprise-search

I've created a list with local columns of Currency type. I created managed properties of text type by going to site collection level 'search schema' and waited for Full crawl to run. This didn't work.

Questions:
1. Why it did not work?
2. How can I map local list columns to managed properties to utilize search?

Edit: [I just opened another thread so understand if I can use managed properties created at SSA at site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223521/mapping-crawled-propertieslist-to-managed-propertiesssa)

Comment: that list search box sucks hard, an answer would help me also

Comment: @Colbs, did you try any fix around it? technically local columns doesn't generate managed properties so search box will not show anything. I'm looking for right place to generate managed properties in such scenarios.

Comment: I haven't tried but you can create managed properties in the Term store and add them as Site Columns or just create managed property on the list

Comment: you'd have to create it as site column not list column.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want to be able to use it as a refiner, for example, query items between $5 and $10?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, I should be at least able to search them. $5 or 5 whatever works.

Comment: So if you just type "5" then you would probably want to use Number or Integer. Make it Searchable. (and good luck number searching is screwy in SP.) I have had much better luck making it refinable instead.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, I found this blog https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/creating-managed-properties-in-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/. The problem is at site collection level allowed data type is only text. Default provided mananged properties are not searchable. Now the only option is to go back to SSA. Q: Can we create a managed property at SSA and map them at site/site-collection level?

Comment: If you want to make Searchable String managed properties you have to use the SSA/Tenant level. These properties are always available to the Site Collections and Site. In SP on-prem you can create properties of all types.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is submitted as research and as partial answer for non number/currency type columns.

From my research til now it seems all columns except number and currency columns would be searchable. For number/currency columns we need to create managed property which is searchable to achieve same.

Unfortunately, at site collection we can only create managed properties of type text and yes/no type. When I mapped crawled properties - for currency columns - search didn't show anything after full crawl.

Next - Since mapping currency type crawled properties to text didn't show up anything after search, I'm looking for a method to enable this.

Pls. follow [this](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/07/what-makes-sharepoint-column-searchable.html) great explanation by Mikael.

Answer (score -1):

Sharepoint will create Managed Property automatically for you. But, you need to add at least one value for the field. Therefore, you can follow steps bellows:

- Created a list with local columns of Currency type
- **Add first item with value in column Currency**
- Run Full Crawl or Incremental Crawl.
- Check your Managed Property.

If you want to create custom mapping between Managed Property and Crawled Property, check this link for details https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx

Comment: That's a crawled property.  You then need to create a managed property and associate the crawled property with it, then perform another full crawl.  The only time a managed property is auto-created is if the column is a site column and then associated with a list (or managed metadata but I'm not sure on the specifics of that)

Comment: To add to GregW, automatic Managed Properties is only in SP2013, in 2016 and SPO MS crippled the feature.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, Thanks for sharing. So in SP2016 we create Managed properties even for Site columns?

Comment: @GregW, Predefined properties like 'refinablestring' are present at sub-site, site-collection and 'central admin' as well. My concern is which one right to use? Also, I'm unable to find documentation which tells the difference. Further, I tried creating a text type managed property at site collection and re ran full crawl. Search is unable to show any result.

Comment: @vicbehal, that has been my experience. You will see some Managed Properties created, sometimes, but they are not decorated with any functional attributes like they are in 2013. If you reuse the Refinable properties, just choose the ones whose data type serves your purpose.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, I can use refinable properties but they are not marked as searchable at site collection level. The managed properties I created at site collection are marked as searchable but search is not shwoing any result.

Comment: @vicbehal true about refinable properties, but if you create them or reuse the non-refinable type field you can apply the searchable attribute. Is the content you are searching for in the same site collection? If not you will have to create Farm/Tenant level properties.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, If use use already provide 'refinaleXX' like 'refinabledecimal or 'non-refinables' like 'decimal', they are not marked as searchable. Since searchable field is disabled, we can't either mark them manually.

Comment: Right, you have to create new managed properties in the SSA.