# Mapping crawled properties(List) to Managed properties(SSA)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

It seems local crawled properties are available at only Site collection level so I thought If I could create some empty managed properties at SSA and map crawl properties at site level. So, I created a few managed properties at SSA.

After making managed properties at SSA I realized these properties are not visible in site collection for mapping. So

1. Are properties created at SSA level managed properties visible at SSA only?
2. If yes, how do we use them? Are 'Site columns' created at site collection have crawled properties which are visible at SSA for mapping? I've local list columns and these crawled properties are not visible at SSA.

[I've another thread where I'm looking for ways to map local list columns to managed properties.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223403/making-sharepoint-list-columns-searchable)

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Site Collection for the Managed Properties you created in the SSA?

Answer (score 1):

Your SSA defined Managed Properties should be available in every Site Collection that is associated with every web application that is associated with your SSA.

> 1. No, they are available to all web applications in the service application association. If you have only one SSA and it is associated with all web applications, your site collections will have the Managed Properties available.
> 2. Use the Managed Properties as you would normally.

Comment: While creating managed properties one need to map it to crawl property. The crawled properties which got created in site collection due to local SharePoint columns are not available in the list that is shown if we create a managed property in SSA.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your SSA configuration or the Web Application is not associated with your SSA because the ONLY way a site collection can "see" a crawled property is if it exists in the SSA.